# vector with hat powered by 2

Tags: math-mode, vector

I'm having some difficulties in making a symbol like the image below, the 2 does not stay where I want, he stays above the vector symbol, or too much below, I want it to stay like in the image below:

[image]

Here is what I try

\hat{\vec{t}^{2}}(s)

Comment: What is your problem? As in, describe your difficulty, please?

Answer (score 1):

Not canonical, but it corrects positioning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\Large

\[
\hat{\!\vec{\,t}}\;^2(s)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it will look better with the `\widehat` accent from `yhmath` and the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, border = 6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{yhmath, accents}%

\begin{document}

  $ \mkern5mu\widehat{\mkern-5mu \rule{0pt}{1.9ex}\smash{\vec{t}}} \vphantom{t}^{\;2}(s) $

\end{document}
```

[image]